# How to use the SQL SPLIT function?

Tags: sql-server

I wish to use the SQL "split" function:

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[Split3] (@String nvarchar(1000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items nvarchar(1000))       
as       
begin       
   declare @idx int       
    declare @slice nvarchar(1000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

   while @idx!= 0       
   begin       
       set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
       if @idx!=0       
           set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
       else       
          set @slice = @String       

       if(len(@slice)>0)  
           insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

       set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
       if len(@String) = 0 break       
   end   
return       
end


Select * from dbo.Split3 ((Select eqipproc from equipmast where eqcode = 'EQL0000004'),';')
```

> ERROR
>
> Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('.
>   Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: why not create a sql clr function ? and use .net framework split function..

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass CSV string to your split function

```
DECLARE @result nvarchar(max)
SET @result = ''

SELECT @result = @result + [eqipproc ] + N';'
equipmast where eqcode = 'EQL0000004'
```

now pass @result to your split function

```
Select * from dbo.Split3(@result,';')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
 CREATE Function dbo.Str_Split(@string varchar(100),@dl varchar(2))
    Returns @outputtbl Table(col varchar(5))
    As
    BEGIN

    Declare @remainingStr varchar(100)=@string
    if(CHARINDEX(@dl,@remainingStr,1) = 0)
    begin
    INSERT INTO @outputtbl
    select @remainingStr
    end
    else
    begin
    While(CHARINDEX(@dl,@remainingStr,1) > 0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @outputtbl
    select LEFT(@remainingStr,CHARINDEX(@dl,@remainingStr,1)-1)
    SET @remainingStr=RIGHT(@remainingStr,LEN(@remainingStr)-CHARINDEX(@dl,@remainingStr,1))
    end
    INSERT INTO @outputtbl
    select @remainingStr
    END

    Return
    END
        --select * from dbo.Str_Split('ab,cd,efg',',')
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter if filtering by `eqcode = 'EQL0000004'` returns only one row or more than one, you can execute your `[dbo].[Split3]` function for each returned row by using [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select s.*
from equipmast as e
cross apply dbo.Split3(e.eqipproc , ';') as s
where e.eqcode = 'EQL0000004'
```

---

Note: the above solution with `CROSS APPLY` does the same like the following (which is similar to [Utkarsh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11721538/6884)):

```
declare @s nvarchar(1000)
select @s = eqipproc from equipmast where eqcode = 'EQL0000004'

select * from dbo.Split3(@s, '.')
```

The difference is that `CROSS APPLY` also works if the query returns more than one row.